# Kernel died, restarting all the time when I try to use tensorflow sessions part (Spyder 3.5)

Tags: session, tensorflow, kernel, spyder

When I try to use tf.Session sess.run() ... my Kernel always died for no reason ... Below is my simple example code applied tf... Can anyone fixed this before ? I have searched on internet, disabled all my firewalls and updated Spyder but it seem not work at all ... My Task Manager showed that my computer used 3% CPU and 30% Memory ... 
.

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,10,10,1]))
filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,1,1]))
op = tf.nn.conv2d(input,filter,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='VALID')
op2 = tf.nn.conv2d(input,filter,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print('Input \n')
    print('{0} \n'.format(input.eval()))
    print('Filter \n')
    print('{0} \n'.format(filter.eval()))
    print('Result with valid position \n')
    result = sess.run(op) <<<<<< **KERNEL DIED here**
    print(result)
    print('\n')
    print('Result with same position \n')
    result2 = sess.run(op2)
    print(result2)
```

[kernel died here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrA0l.png)